# Where would this question go: "Why is the drop shadow light source always upper left?"

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this really fits with graphic design, ux, or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should go back to the question factory for a redesign.  It fits the "Not a real question" close criteria to a T:

> **not a real question**
>   It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Perhaps it's the word "always" that makes the Q objectionable. The fact that drop shadows in 2D layouts *most often* have a top left light source is a valid observation, even if the answer isn't very interesting.

Comment: @Alan Now that you mention it...  is the *most often* at all related to left-to-right reading direction?  Would art in cultures with right-to-left reading direction be more likely to have light-sources in the top-right corner?

Comment: I wouldn't close or flag such a question. I don't think that this question is "not a real question". This is only the subject of the question, the body is not mentioned by @tajmo, so maybe there is a further explanation why this is asked. I would tag such a question "design-principles". (Some info about me: Flag weight of 697 at SO)

Comment: @Ocaso Granted we cannot see the body, but (as in this question), we really only have the title to go on.  Additionally, the title makes an assumption that simply isn't valid.  This would be akin to a SO question "Why are all VBA macros written in Excel?"  I'm not sure that I'd flag it for close - the resulting discussion might reveal interesting details about thought processes.  Despite how thankful I am for good answers to bad questions, it still remains that this would be a low-quality question that could stand some improvement.

Comment: @Farray: Now THAT would be quite a decent question! There are natural (the sun mostly shines from above) and conventional (Kodak's bad but often-followed advice about keeping the sun over your left shoulder when taking snapshots, for example) reasons. But the source of most layout drop-shadows is InDesign (which Mike Ninness actually apologized for recently), and 135 degrees is its default. Photoshop's default is similar. Prosaic, I know, but we tend to be lazy about relatively unimportant details. Technology often drives fashion, and this is more fashion than anything else.

Comment: Of course, as @Alan mentioned, a "most often" would be a helpful addition to the title to improve the question and this can be done with a comment and an edit. But it is hard to tell from the title that the question is low quality. There is always a gray area concerning quality. And as you can see from the comments here: The question is really interesting ;)

Comment: @Alan: Comes the questions what was first: The 135 degree default or the light source in the upper left corner?

Comment: @Ocaso: I didn't want to get into that. Too much like discussing how many angels can dance on a corner point, but not as useful.:-D